# Livestreaming using red5 and rtmp and jwplayer

Tags: php, red5, jwplayer, rtmp

I can't access red5 using rtmp. I don't know what the problem is.
I have given like

```
'streamer': 'rtmp://192.168.0.6/oflaDemo'
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

There's usually a stream name which you should pass in using the "file" parameter. Can you provide the full configuration you're using to create the player?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this statement.

```
'streamer': 'rtmp://192.168.0.6:1935/oflaDemo'
```

192.168.0.6 should be your vps or dedicated server's IP.